# dynamically update d3.js treemap

Tags: javascript, dynamic, d3.js, treemap

I am trying to dynamically update my d3 treemap when the data updates. I have two functions, one that I call initially to build the treemap and another to redraw the treemap. When I redraw the treemap, I get a thin black bar on top of the treemap, and the first element in the array that I am graphing goes black. If I click on either of the two black elements. I get the error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dx' of undefined
```

So the data being passed to the cell is undefined.

Additionally when I call regraph I have checked and the data has changed, but the graph is unchanged from when I initially built the treemap with the exception of the two black elements.

The code for building the treemap is below. Also the createObj function takes two arrays and creates a Json object.

```
 function drawTreeMap(array1,array2){
        console.log("got to drawing");
        nestedJson=createObj(array1, array2);
            w = 1880 - 80,
            h = 900 - 180,
            x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
            color = d3.scale.linear()
                .range(['lightgreen', 'darkgreen']) // or use hex values
                .domain([computeMin(array2), computeMaxNum(array2)]);
            root,
            node;


            treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                .round(false)
                .size([w, h])
                .sticky(true)
                .padding([10, 0, 0, 0])
                .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

            svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "chart")
                .style("width", w + "px")
                .style("height", h + "px")
              .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
              .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");


              node = root = nestedJson;

              var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

              var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
                  .data(nodes)
                  .enter().append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "cell")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                  .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

              cell.append("svg:rect")
                  .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
                  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy ; })
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.size)});

              cell.append("svg:text")
                  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text(function(d) { return (d.name+",--  "+d.size); })
                  .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });




              d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

              d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
                treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
                zoom(node);
              });

    }
```

The code for redrawing is below.

```
function redrawGraphFromJson(data) {
      treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .round(false)
        .size([w,h])
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
        .sticky(true);

      // Draw the graph
      node = root = data;
      var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

      var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(nodes)
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

    cell.append("svg:rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy ; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.size);});

    cell.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return (d.name+",--  "+d.size); })
        .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your redrawing of the graph, you are going to want to .exit() on the initial graph and then .enter() to update the groups with the new data. This will replace the old map with the new.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ explains it perfectly and has a really good example to look at.